# How do I delete mongrel temp files after completion of upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel

In my rails application am uploading some large file(1 Gb),and
when I go windows temp folder, mongrel temporary files are gathering
there, but I would like these files to be deleted after upload
completes.

Could anyone tell me how do that??

This is my ruby version:
ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32]

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

either GC.start or possibly hack into the guts of mongrel...

Comment: Thanks for respond rogerdpack